# Pyspark Order By 1.5B Records With 20 Distinct Values - Performance Issue

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following code:

```
    cache_df = cache_df.orderBy(f.col('last_update').asc()).limit(10000000)
```

Cache_df contains 350M records and I want to get 10M with the oldest last_update value.
It seems like the reduce operation of the order by order all the data in 1 executor and I am not executing this operation in parallel way
Any idea how to solve it?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

See this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/sort-vs-orderby-in-spark-8a912475390) explains the order by:
*"orderBy() collects all the data into a single executor and then sorts them. This means that the order of the output data is guaranteed but this is probably a very costly operation."*